# Segmentation Fault C++ Number of islands

Tags: c++, graph-theory, depth-first-search

The problem is to find number of islands which is basically dfs, it is working cool for short test cases but for large cases it has segmentation fault.

```
int isSafe(
    vector<vector<char>> &grid,
    int row,
    int col,
    vector<vector<bool>> &visited)
{
    return ((row >= 0) &&
            (row < grid.size()) &&
            (col >= 0) &&
            (col < grid[0].size()) &&
            (grid[row][col] == '1') &&
            !visited[row][col]);
}
void DFS(
    vector<vector<char>> &grid,
    int row, int col,
    vector<vector<bool>> &visited)
{
    int rowNbr[8] = {-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
    int colNbr[8] = {-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1};
    visited[row][col] = true;
    for (int k = 0; k < 8; ++k)
        if (isSafe(grid, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], visited))
            DFS(grid, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], visited);
}
int numIslands(vector<vector<char>> &grid)
{
    // Code here
    if (grid.empty())
        return 0;
    int Row = grid.size();
    int Col = grid[0].size();
    vector<vector<bool>> visited(Row, vector<bool>(Col, false));
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Row; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < Col; ++j)
        {
            if ((grid[i][j] == '1') && !visited[i][j])
            {
                DFS(grid, i, j, visited);
                ++count;
            }
        }
    return count;
}
```

why this code has segmentation fault for large test cases where Row=500 and Col=500. It is working fine for short test cases.

Comment: Can you give the question first?

Comment: One possible problem can be due to too many recursive function calls. Try usinh iterative BFS

Comment: Your recursive function DFS does not modify grid.  Therefore grid does not need to be passed in the parameter list.  Make grid a global, saving stack memory and allowing you to handle larger problems.